# Mysql PDO search that has to have certain words

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking for a way to search a mysql field using PHP's PDO MySQL functions where the field has to contain the entered keywords.

I currently have a simple LIKE %terms% type of search, but that's not good for finding something specific, what if someone wants to search for items that have to have certain words in them, is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: Read about database normalisation. ... may help

Comment: This is nothing to do with database normalisation, this is about keyword searching.

Comment: I have also read that page and can't figure it out, as the full-text searching seems to always remove common "stop" words, i don't want that.

Comment: Given that the common stopwords are managed in a table maintained by you (as the developer), you're in full control of what words it contains.... leave it empty if you don't want stopwords to be removed